How do I change the length of the ScrollPane?
I want to change the inner size of the scrollPane.
I've tried various methods to do it but I couldn't. I want it so that everytime tasks are created, the ScrollPane's length changes. (It like senses whether the JPanel is full then the scrollBar's length increases).
I have a Task class (Its simply what generates the tasks)
This is my List class (Places the tasks on a list):
package com.chri_stw.todolist;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class List extends JPanel {

    private int cornerRadius; // Allows customization of the corner radius

    List() {
        this.cornerRadius = 30; // Default corner radius
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(10, 1);
        layout.setVgap(5);  // Vertical gap between components

        this.setLayout(layout);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));  // Preferred size
        this.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        add(new Task());
        setOpaque(false); // Set the panel to be non-opaque to show rounded corners
    }

    // Override paintComponent to add rounded edges
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); // Smooth edges
        g2.setColor(getBackground());
        g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), cornerRadius, cornerRadius); // Draw rounded background
        super.paintComponent(g2);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    public void updateNumbers() {
        Component[] listItems = this.getComponents();

        for (int i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
            if (listItems[i] instanceof Task) {
                ((Task) listItems[i]).changeIndex(i + 1);  // Update task index
            }
        }
        revalidate();  // Ensure layout recalculation
        repaint();  // Ensure the panel is redrawn
    }

    public void removeCompletedTasks() {

        for (Component c : getComponents()) {
            if (c instanceof Task) {
                if (((Task) c).getState()) {
                    remove(c);  // Remove completed tasks
                }
            }
        }
        updateNumbers();  // Update task indices
        revalidate();  // Recalculate layout after removing tasks
        repaint();  // Redraw the panel
    }

    // Method to add tasks to the list
    public void addTask(Task task) {
        this.add(task);  // Add task to the panel
        revalidate();  // Ensure that layout updates after adding the task
        repaint();  // Redraw the panel to reflect the new task
    }

    // Force setting the size explicitly, in case revalidation does not update it
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(350, 560);  // Ensure preferred size
    }
}

And this is the AppFrame (Finalizes all the UI):
package com.chri_stw.todolist;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI;

public class AppFrame extends JFrame {

    private TitleBar title;
    private Footer footer;
    private List list;

    private JButton newTask;
    private JButton clear;

    AppFrame() {
        // Set default frame properties
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);

        // Initialize components
        title = new TitleBar();
        footer = new Footer();
        list = new List();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JScrollBar scroll = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
        scrollPane.setBorder(null);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll.setUI(new BasicScrollBarUI() {
            @Override
            protected void configureScrollBarColors() {
                this.thumbColor = Color.gray;
            }
        });
        scroll.setUnitIncrement(1); // Smooth scrolling
        scroll.setForeground(Color.gray);

        add(scrollPane);

        // Add components to the frame
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(footer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Initialize footer buttons
        newTask = footer.getNewTask();
        clear = footer.getClear();

        // Add listeners to buttons
        addListeners();

        // Adjust frame size and make it visible
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 700));
        this.pack(); // Adjust size based on preferred sizes
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame on the screen
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    

    public void addListeners() {
        // Listener for "New Task" button
        newTask.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                Task task = new Task();
                list.add(task);
                list.updateNumbers();

                task.getDone().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        task.toggleState(); // Toggle the task's state
                        list.updateNumbers();
                        revalidate();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Listener for "Clear" button
        clear.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                list.removeCompletedTasks(); // Remove completed tasks
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}



Have your List class override getPreferredSize in an intelligent fashion.

It looks like you may make things easier if you just use a JList to display your tasks.

I’m not sure I understand what you want, but I suspect you can solve your problem by having your List class implement Scrollable. JScrollPane behaves more reliably when its view child implements Scrollable.

The issue arises because the JScrollPane relies on the preferred size of its viewport (in your case, the List panel) to calculate the scrollable area. If the preferred size isn’t updated dynamically, the scrollable region will remain fixed, causing the scrollbar to behave incorrectly.
Modify the List panel’s preferred size based on the number of tasks it contains. Add the following method to your List class:
public void updatePreferredSize() {
    int taskHeight = 50;
    int gap = 5;
    int totalHeight = (taskHeight + gap) * this.getComponentCount() - gap;
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, Math.max(totalHeight, 400)));
}

Call the updatePreferredSize() method whenever tasks are added, removed, or updated:
public void addTask(Task task) {
    this.add(task);
    updatePreferredSize();
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}

public void removeCompletedTasks() {
    for (Component c : getComponents()) {
        if (c instanceof Task) {
            if (((Task) c).getState()) {
                remove(c);
            }
        }
    }
    updatePreferredSize();
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}

public void updateNumbers() {
    Component[] listItems = this.getComponents();

    for (int i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        if (listItems[i] instanceof Task) {
            ((Task) listItems[i]).changeIndex(i + 1);
        }
    }
    updatePreferredSize();
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}

Avoid setting a fixed preferred size for the List panel in AppFrame. Let the dynamic updates handle it.

(1-) As was suggested in the first comment to the question, you should override the getPreferredSize() method of the panel to dynamically reflect the desired size.
